# Why does readline() echo stdin to stdout?

Tags: c, readline

I've written a small C program that uses `readline("")` to read input from stdin.  Rather than interacting with it from the terminal, I've written a test harness which executes the C program and gives it input:

```
test harness --stdout--> | --stdin--> C program
         ^------stdin--- | <--stdout-----/
```

This test harness is receiving an echo of its output, even though the program itself.  Why is readline() echoing its input, and can I disable this?  Or should I not be using readline() in a non-interactive environment?

Comment: What's wrong with `fread`?

Comment: could you please post some code?

Comment: Actually as the answer below suggests, `fgets` is probably more relevant, since it also reads by line.

Comment: @Dave `readline()` is convenient since it strips newlines and dynamically allocates `char*` buffers for me.  And I'd like to use its interactive features when launched interactively.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The [readline](http://www.gnu.org/software/readline/) library is solely intended for interactive use. Your program should probably fall back to using `fgets()` if `isatty(STDIN_FILENO)` is false.

Comment: Wouldn't [`getline()` be preferable to `fgets()`](http://crasseux.com/books/ctutorial/fgets.html)?

Comment: Perhaps. The distinction seems unlikely to matter for applications where you would otherwise use `readline()`, though.

Answer (score 2):

By default Readline echos user input to stdout, however it is configurable.

From readline [documentation](http://web.mit.edu/gnu/doc/html/rlman_2.html):

> Variable: FILE * **rl_outstream**
>
> The stdio stream to which Readline performs output.

Just set `rl_outstream` to `stderr` in beginning of your program, so it will echoing to stderr instead; For example:

```c
#include <readline/readline.h>
#include <stdio.h>
...
int main() {
    rl_outstream = stderr;
...
```

In fact **bash(1)** does this too.

And I also agree that if your program isn't designed to be used interactively, your should use another simpler way to get lines from stdin, such as **getline(3)**, **fgets(3)** or **getchar(3)**.