# How to control input echoing in non-interactive mode with readline 8.2?

Tags: c, bash, readline

As part of a school project, we have to write a simplified shell and are instructed to imitate Bash's behavior.
While trying to understand how to make the simplified shell work in non-interactive mode, I noticed 2 issues:

1. readline is echoing input to stdout, regardless of whether stdin, stdout or stderr are connected to a terminal
2. when neither stdout or stderr are connected to the terminal, you can't see what you're typing.

What i need is:

- When you're entering input from the terminal, you need to see what you type, even if stdout and stderr are redirected away from the terminal.
- When taking input from a file, the contents of the input file should not be echoed to either stdout or stderr.

I saw here ([Why does readline() echo stdin to stdout?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15467164/why-does-readline-echo-stdin-to-stdout)) that you can configure this behaviour using the `rl_outstream` variable, but this doesn't seem enough.
In non-interactive mode, i need to disable input echoing completely. But setting `rl_outstream = NULL` just makes it echo to stdout.

Here is the code that shows my issue:

```c
#include <stdio.h>
#include <readline/readline.h>
#include <readline/history.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <unistd.h>

int main()
{
    char    *line;

    if (isatty(2))
        rl_outstream = stderr;

    while (1)
    {
        if (isatty(0) && isatty(2))
            line = readline("prompt> ");
        else
            line = readline("");
        if (!line)
            break ;
        free(line);
    }
    return (0);
}
```

Make sure to compile with readline 8.2.1, since this code seems to behave differently with older versions of readline.

When running `./a.out >out` or `./a.out 2>err`, i get the result i want.
My problem is with the following cases:

`./a.out >out 2>err` Problem: Can't see what you type

`./a.out <infile` Problem: Input is echoed to stderr

Comment: The question you linked suggests `readline()` is not appropriate for non-interactive use.

Answer (score 1):

Frame challenge:

[The Bash manual page](https://linux.die.net/man/1/bash) has this to say about readline:

> This is the library that handles reading input *when using an interactive shell*, unless the `--noediting` option is given at shell invocation. Line editing is also used when using the `-e` option to the `read` builtin.

(Emphasis added)

We can conclude, then, that Bash itself does not use readline when running as a non-interactive shell.  You can even disable readline for interactive Bash.

Thus, you should consider emulating Bash in this regard too, and instead of struggling with making readline work as you want for the non-interactive case, just don't use it in that case.